# Need help to modify a Shell Script to change ip addresses on CentOS

Tags: bash, shell, networking, centos

I have a shell script to change IP address (on a CentOS), instead of changing it manually. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# changeip.sh

usage(){
    clear
    echo "Usage: $0 newip"
    echo "Example: $0 127.0.0.1"
    exit 1
}

new_ip_value=$1
local_ip_value=$(ifconfig eth0|awk '/inet addr/ {split ($2,A,":"); print A[2]}')

# call usage() function if filename not supplied
    [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && usage


echo "/etc/hosts"
echo "----------------------------------------------------------"
sed -ie 's/'$local_ip_value'/'$new_ip_value'/g' /etc/hosts
sed 's/'$local_ip_value'/'$new_ip_value'/g' /etc/hosts
echo ""
echo "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0"
echo "----------------------------------------------------------"
sed -ie 's/'$local_ip_value'/'$new_ip_value'/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
sed 's/'$local_ip_value'/'$new_ip_value'/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
echo "The IP of $local_ip_value has successfully been changed to $new_ip_value."
service network restart

exit
```

I need to add further parameters like:

1. BOOTPROTO
2. ONBOOT
3. GATEWAY
4. DNS1

and so on.

Could any body let me know how i should modify the script to add these details? My ifcfg-eth0 should ultimately like this:

```
# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE="Ethernet"
IPADDR=192.168.1.2
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A much better way to change IP addresses on CentOS is to use the `system-network-config-cmd` tool.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Shell script input parsing here

system-config-network-cmd -i <<EOF
DeviceList.Ethernet.eth0.type=Ethernet
DeviceList.Ethernet.eth0.BootProto=static
DeviceList.Ethernet.eth0.OnBoot=True
DeviceList.Ethernet.eth0.NMControlled=True
DeviceList.Ethernet.eth0.Netmask=192.168.1.255
DeviceList.Ethernet.eth0.IP=${new_ip_value}
DeviceList.Ethernet.eth0.Gateway=192.168.1.1
ProfileList.default.ActiveDevices.1=eth0
EOF

service network stop
service network start
```

If you run as `system-config-network-cmd -e` it dumps the existing configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could please let me know can i automate the process using system-config-network-cmd -i? My whole point is to automate the process and not to configure it manualally.

Comment: The answer shows code you can put in a shell script... `system-config-network-cmd -i` accepts its commands on stdin; do a search for 'Bash Here Document' for an explanation of how it is working.

Comment: I edited the answer to use your shell variable, hope that shows what I meant

Comment: Thanks for your reply again! My understanding now is, to put the configurations in a file, say config.sh and run it. Upon running the script, it is going to ask me to enter the Static IP address that i want. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the boot proto as it is and change the required fields.

IP
Netmask
Gateway
DNS

Rest will be used the same for both IP configurations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).